# Selenium code with python 3. I cannot figure out why is this code not working, its set up all corectly

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, boolean

is_selected in selenium

```
check_box = root.find_element(By.XPATH,'//label[@for="full-stamina-heavy-toggle"]').is_selected()
    sleep(1)
    if check_box == True:
        pass
    elif check_box == False:
        stamina.click()
    else:
        print('checkboxfail ')
```

does anybody know whats up ?

i checked out official docs, and some side tutorials but all uses this command just like me, is_selected() comes back with bool, well not in my case tho

Comment: Where is `is_selected()` in your code? What does it return instead?

Comment: well, I doubt that a label can be "selected", perhaps you are looking for a wrong element, <input type="checkbox"> or something like that is a checkbox

Comment: solved thx :) mr Danny was right, i didnt set it up properly